# Geometry of Curves

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I found this question in question paper of Geometry of Curves and surfaces from Leeds University. 
Can anyone help me how I solve it.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look up "involute" so that you might, yourself, have some hope of completing part "(a)"? It's a pretty well-established term.

Comment: I have no problem with part (a). What about part (b)?

Comment: Just differentiate your parametrization $\gamma(t)$ and use the basic definitions (even given in the problem). The only difficulty is to use the chain rule to correct for that fact that $|I_\gamma'(t)|\ne 1$, which means that $I_\gamma$ is *not* unit speed.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've done so far on part b, following Ted's advice? (BTW, asking us how to do parts you can already solve is seriously rude.)